# Efficient way of porting MATLAB code to optimized C

Tags: c, matlab, optimization, signal-processing, porting

When porting a complex MATLAB application to an embedded platform running native C, is the MATLAB-to-C code generation efficient and useful to get a (slow) starting point that I can then profile and optimize, or am I better off writing my application in C from scratch despite the added complexity of having to rewrite the entire code in C manually?

My concern is that MATLAB being vector-oriented, the generated C-code may just be so remote from how one would write code in C that I am just going to waste time trying to generate any code automatically and never actually use any of the generated code.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed similar question with useful answer. It suggests that for a one-time conversion from MATLAB to C, and assuming I am not using some libraries off the beaten path, the MATLAB coder may be the way to go.  Wondering if others will have a different take on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need both MATLAB Coder and [Embedded Coder](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder/) to customize and optimize the generated for the embedded target. I suggest you have a look for example at [MATLAB to C Code Generation with Embedded MATLAB](http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-to-c-code-generation-with-embedded-matlab-81713.html) or other videos/webinars on the subject to get a better idea of what's involved.

Comment: There is also a [documentation section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/optimize-speed-of-generated-code.html) on optimizing performance of the generated code. Some suggestions are to edit your MATLAB code (e.g. loops are OK when generating code, or use `PARFOR` which translates to multi-threaded OpenMP code) and others suggest changing settings in the code generation project.